# Xcode bug? VoiceOver with TableView

Tags: xcode, tableview, voiceover

I was just wondering is this an existing bug OR is there anyway to fix this. When in tableview, turning on voiceover will result in empty table cells... anyone?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";

//Exisint bug if using TableViewCell
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell.
cell.pLabel.text = [self.tableArrayPlaces objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *selectedDest = [tableArrayPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Get the selected country
NSLog(@"SelectedDest %@", selectedDest);
}
```

Edited: Codes are added. This is my codes for populating my cells. In storyboard I set it to "push", can't seem to work. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell.    
cell.text = [tableArrayPlaces objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

return cell;
}
```

Instead of using my own cellView, I used UITableViewCell. This solves my problem. But of course I can no longer do any linking at my storyboard directly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug in iOS or in your code, but it's probably not a bug in Xcode.

Check your table view controller's `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Is it being called when the empty cells are generated? If no, why not? If yes, is it returning properly formatted cells? Can you reproduce the problem in other applications such as Contacts?

Comment: Good idea. Tried on contacts. There's no problem... I guess it's my codes.